# Accessing SQLalchemy from a class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm making a project where I need to create a class instance which has methods which connect to a db and fetch data from it (I'm using SQLite as a backend).
I've had some experience with flask-sqlalchemy, but I'm lost when it comes to pure SQLAlchemy.
The concept is as follows:
User creates an instance of `DataSet`, and passes a path to the database as an `__init__` parameter. If the database already exists, I would like just to connect to it and do queries, if it doesn't, I want to create a new one using a model. But I can't understand how to do so.

Here's the `DataSet` code:

```
from os.path import normcase, split, join, isfile
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import errors
import trainset
import testset


class DataSet:
    def __init__(self, path_to_set, path_to_db, train_set=False, path_to_labels=None, label_dict=None,
                 custom_name=None):
        self.__path_to_set = path_to_set
        self.__label_dict = label_dict

        if custom_name is None:
            dbpath = join(path_to_db, 'train.db')
            if train_set is False:
                dbpath = join(path_to_db, 'test.db')
        else:
            dbpath = join(path_to_db, custom_name)
        if isfile(dbpath):
            self.__prepopulated = True
        else:
            self.__prepopulated = False
        self.__dbpath = dbpath

        if train_set is True and path_to_labels is None:
            raise errors.InsufficientData('labels', 'specified')
        if train_set is True and not isfile(path_to_labels):
            raise errors.InsufficientData('labels', 'found at specified path', path_to_labels)

    def prepopulate(self):
        engine = create_engine('sqlite:////' + self.__dbpath)
        self.__prepopulated = True
```

Here's the `trainset` code:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, PickleType, Integer, MetaData

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = MetaData()


class TrainSet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'train set'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    real_id = Column(String(60))
    path = Column(String(120))
    labels = Column(PickleType)
    features = Column(PickleType)
```

Here's the `testset` code:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, PickleType, Integer, MetaData

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = MetaData()


class TestSet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test set'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    real_id = Column(String(60))
    path = Column(String(120))
    features = Column(PickleType)
```

So, if the user passes `train_set=True` when creating a `DataSet` instance, I would like to create a database using the `TrainSet` model, and create a `TestSet` database otherwise. I would like this to happen in the `prepopulate` method, however, I don't  understand how to do it - the documentation calls for this: `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`, but I'm lost as to where to put this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First save the parameter `train_set`:

```
class DataSet:
    def __init__(self, path_to_set, path_to_db, train_set=False, path_to_labels=None, label_dict=None,
                 custom_name=None):
        self._train_set = train_set
        # ...
```

Then, use it in the `prepopulate` to create proper model(s):

```
def prepopulate(self):
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:////' + self.__dbpath)
    if self._train_set:
        trainset.Base.create_all(engine)
    else:
        testset.Base.create_all(engine)
    self.__prepopulated = True
```

---

*One more thing: do not prefix your "private" variables with double-underscore. Please read [`PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) for reference.*

Comment: Great, thanks! I only had to change `testset.Base.create_all(engine)` to `testset.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` (same goes for `train set`), but it all works now.
Also, since I will be writing a lot of functions which query stuff, is it a good idea to store the engine in the class instance? (Instead of creating it in each class method)?

Comment: I would not store engine in any of the model classes, as you will be mixing wrong things together and will get everything coupled in a wierd way (*model* should not know anything about the *connection*). Instead, in the class methods just use [`object_session(self)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.object_session) to get the session (a-la `transaction`) and query other data as required.